# Can I send push notification on iPhone based on its location (without the app running)?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I have this requirement from client where depending on the location of the iPhone we need to send push notification. Now how can we find location of the iPhone without the app running in background? Is there anyway we can achieve this?

Comment: did you end up getting a solution working for your question?  I am looking to also use a location based push service in one of my projects and wasn't sure if going the route of a background task with Significant-Change Location Service or utilizing "Monitoring Shape-Based Regions" would be best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recently-released iPhone OS 4, I believe this is now possible.  See http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html.

Edit: More useful info [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).  See the section entitled "Starting the Significant-Change Location Service"

Answer (score 1):

no, an SDK app must be running (and therefore in the foreground) to be able to send any location data.

.mac can do this with the locate my iphone feature, but it requires a subscription and as far as I know cant be used by an external application...