# How to achieve ios local push notification based on user location without running app in the background and draining battery?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We got a requirement that the app need to send local push notifications when the user goes to particular location using the users current latitude and longitude values.eg.shopping mall.

Requirement 1.
The app should able to send the notification even if the app is not running in the background.

Requirement 2.
The should not drain too much battery.

I request all ios experts to help me on achieving this functionality. I have tried everywhere but unable to find solutions for this.

I saw ibotta app achieved the same functionality.

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Eniyan R

Comment: duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769880/can-i-send-push-notification-on-iphone-based-on-its-location-without-the-app-ru?rq=1

Comment: I saw the thread previously, but there was not enough information available. I have mentioned an example app named ibotta.

Answer (score 0):

[Region Monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW1) is imho best. There are other methods, but this is most suitable way for your situation.